# Run a function when importing module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, python-import

What I want to achieve: I have a function (object/module/etc) that allows me to run a model. This model requires a few parameters, so I want to have them in a config file rather than pass all through the code. So what I want is to have a config file created automatically when my module is imported. Is it possible in python? Can I have some pointers on where to start please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the code in a python file is run when its imported. If you have

```py
def f():
  print("ran")

print("imported")
```

Then when you import it it will print `imported`
This is also why you sometimes see `if __name__=="__main__":`
In some files. The code in that block is only run if the file is run as main not imported.
However creating files in a predetermined location may be bad UX, so if you want other people to use your library id think of a better solution.

Generally you can just put code at top level of a module and it will run.

Comment: Thank you very much @DownloadPizza, it's very helpful! Import system is one of those areas in python I didn't properly dive in yet. In terms of UX, I agree, there got to be better ways, still, very good to know and explore the options!